# show an image on a div before setting the same div with some text REACT.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, jsx

Im making a chatting application in which i get the response from the back end and it is displayed without any delay. I am mapping the messages after setting the state `Chat` with the messages of . 
Below is the response I get from the back end.

```
 var tesBotMessages = this.state.Chat.map(function (msg, key) {
       <div className="chat chat-left pull-left">
                    {(msg.Botresponse === undefined || msg.Botresponse === "")
                        ? <div className="chat-body chat-bubbles">
                            <div className="chat-content">
                                <p>Sorry I don't get it.. :(</p>
                                <time className="chat-time"></time></div>
                           </div>
                         :<div className="chat-body chat-bubbles">
                            <div className="chat-content" id="textporgress">
                                <p id="message">{msg.Botresponse}</p>
                                <time className="chat-time"></time></div>
                        </div>}  
                       </div>
```

How can I show an image on this JSX `id="message"` before showing the actual `<p>{msg.Botresponse}</p>` Here I first check if the the response undefined of null. if its not null it is displayed.

I just need to show it for an interval of 1 second.

Comment: You only have to show the image in the last message right?

Comment: yes.. a way which only shows the image to the latest message in the state NOT ALL

Comment: You've to use setTimeout and set a state variable showImage to true before the setTimeout, after the timeout set it to false.
In your JSX you can have one more condition check (key === this.state.Chat.length -1 && this.state.showImage) then show <img> otherwise show <p> tag.